# Trying to setup my own pool and having problems connecting to my server

Tags: mining-pools, pushpool

So I've setup my own `Pushpool` server, and now I'm trying to connect using `GUIMiner`

The server is up and running, this is what my terminal says:

```
sbin/pushpoold -E -F
[2013-04-19 20:33:5.395392] Listening on host :: port 8336
[2013-04-19 20:33:5.395592] Listening on host :: port 8337
[2013-04-19 20:33:5.395792] initialized
```

and on the GUIminer I connect with

```
Host: http://localhost
Port: 8336
Username: username (what I have set in SQLite3)
Password: password
```

But then when I start mining my console says this

```
2013-04-18 14:40:53: Running command: poclbm.exe username:password@http://localhost:8336 --device=0 --platform=0 --verbose -r1 
2013-04-18 14:40:53: Listener for "Default" started
2013-04-18 14:40:54: Listener for "Default": 18/04/2013 14:40:54,  need more than 1 value to unpack
2013-04-18 14:40:56: Listener for "Default": WARNING: ADL missing (no AMD platform?), temperature control is disabled
2013-04-18 14:40:56: Listener for "Default": At least one server is required
2013-04-18 14:40:56: Listener for "Default": Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-04-18 14:40:56: Listener for "Default": File "Switch.pyo", line 45, in __init__
2013-04-18 14:40:56: Listener for "Default": File "Switch.pyo", line 60, in parse_server
2013-04-18 14:40:56: Listener for "Default": ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
2013-04-18 14:40:57: Listener for "Default" shutting down
```

Anybody here have any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the server the wrong way. The way you note the server's address isn't valid URI syntax.

Bad :

```
username:password@http://localhost:8336
```

Good :

```
http://username:password@localhost:8336
```